# Sahi case sensitive issue

Tags: sahi

I have come across and issue where different browsers return fields in different cases (upper, lower). For the most part the following method works for me:

```
_click(_link("/Next/i"));
```

However I have one item on the web page with brackets in the name and this approach does not work:

```
_assert(_isVisible(_link("/Noticeboard(Active Tab)/i")));
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Regards

Comment: Please try with:
_assert(_isVisible(_link("/Noticeboard[(]Active Tab[)]/i")));

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

_assert(_isVisible(_link("/Noticeboard\(Active Tab\)/i")));

The back slash is meant to escape the real purpose of "(".